# Помогите достать текст Python Parser

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, requests

добрый день подскажите как вытащить название корабля.

```
    <div class="page-title no-back-link">
<h1>AEGEAN ANGEL</h1>
<div class="byline">Tankship</div>
<div title="Greece" class="flag-icon flag-icon-large flag-icon-gr">
</div></div>
```

Вызываю получаю текст.

```
name = blok_ship2.find('div',class_='page-title no-back-link')
print(name)
```

На выходи имею:

```
AEGEAN ANGELTankship
```

Хочу получить только название AEGEAN ANGEL.

P.S.:просто удалить Tankship не прокатит везде тип судна разный.
Заранее спасибо!!

Comment: Для таких целей лучше задать отдельный класс тексту, вы можете изменять этот html?

Comment: нет это html с сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можете использовать `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html = """
 <div class="page-title no-back-link">
<h1>AEGEAN ANGEL</h1>
<div class="byline">Tankship</div>
<div title="Greece" class="flag-icon flag-icon-large flag-icon-gr">
</div></div>
"""


soup = Soup(html, 'html.parser')


title = soup.find("h1").getText(strip=True)

print(title)
```

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую!

Comment: Да спасибо всё отлично)